# Keyboard Input Movement on Applet

Tags: java, applet, awt, game-engine, keylistener

I'm creating a very basic game using applet and I'm not sure how to write the code for the computer to register the arrows as movement (up, down, left, right).

How can I get the yellow Pacman looking character to move based on keyboard inputs?

This is my code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GameShopRoofCashOut extends Applet 
{
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        // Setup the board
        int rows = 20;
        int columns = 20;
        int cellSize = 30;                          
        int board [ ][ ] = new int [rows][columns]; 
        int dirt = 12;
        int lightstone = 13;
        int darkstone = 17;
        int slotx = 12;
        int sloty = 0;
        int linex = 30;
        int liney = 390;
        int layer = 0;

        // Store objects in the board
        board[11][4] = 7;
        board[11][5] = 7;
        board[10][14] = 8;
        board[11][14] = 9;
        board[0][19] = 10;
        while (sloty<20)
        {
            while (slotx<20)
            { 
                for (int r=0; r< board.length; r++)  
                {
                    for (int c=0; c< board[r].length; c++)
                    { 
                        //store objects in the board
                        board[dirt][sloty] = 1;
                        board[lightstone][sloty] = 2;
                        board[darkstone][sloty]= 3;
                        if (lightstone<17)
                        {
                            lightstone++;
                        }
                        if (darkstone<19)
                        {
                            darkstone++;
                        }
                        // Draw the board

                        if (board [r][c] == 1)      
                        {
                            g.setColor(Color.blue);
                            g.fillRect(c*cellSize,r*cellSize,cellSize,cellSize);
                            layer++;
                        }
                        if (board [r][c] == 2)      
                        {
                            g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
                            g.fillRect(c*cellSize,r*cellSize,cellSize,cellSize);
                            layer++;
                        }
                        if (board [r][c] == 3)      
                        {
                            g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
                            g.fillRect(c*cellSize,r*cellSize,cellSize,cellSize);
                            layer++;
                        }
                        if (board [r][c] == 7)      
                        {
                            g.setColor(Color.magenta);
                            g.fillRect(c*cellSize,r*cellSize,cellSize,cellSize);
                            layer++;
                        }
                        if (board[r][c] == 8)
                        {
                            int x = c*cellSize;
                            int y = r*cellSize;
                            Polygon p = new Polygon(); 
                            p.addPoint(x+cellSize/2,y); 
                            p.addPoint(x+cellSize, y+cellSize); 
                            p.addPoint(x, y+cellSize); 
                            p.addPoint(x+cellSize/2,y); 
                            g.setColor(Color.orange);
                            g.fillPolygon(p);
                        }
                        if (board[r][c] == 9)
                        {
                            g.setColor(Color.orange);
                            g.fillRect(c*cellSize,r*cellSize,cellSize,cellSize);

                        }
                        if (board [r][c] == 10)      
                        {
                            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                            g.fillArc(c*cellSize,r*cellSize,cellSize,cellSize,30,300);
                        }
                    }
                }
                slotx++;
            }
            lightstone = 13;
            darkstone = 17;
            slotx=12;
            sloty++;
        }
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("Shop",420,295);
        g.drawString("Cash Out",120,320);
        while (linex<600)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawLine(linex,360,linex,600);
            g.drawLine(0,liney,600,liney);
            linex+=30;
            liney+=30;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited out the extra parts in the title, and the tag of the IDE, as they were largely irrelevant. Seriously, I feel for you. There is no excuse for schools to be teaching applets (made obsolete) or expect code using AWT components in this day and age. The quality of answers on SO will be less than optimal, since few people knew the intricacies of applets and those who coded AWT apps have also largely forgotten the details. So ask your teacher this first: Is the task to learn obsolete / obsolescent APIs, or to understand how to create animated games? Report back.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you! We are attempting to understand how to create animated games, my code obviously isn't finished yet but the premise of the game is for the character to find a hidden object that will be randomly stored in one of the dark stones that are generated. So all I'm really trying to figure out is how I can use the arrow keys to animate the motion of the Pacman like character.  Thanks again!

Comment: So .. when I wrote *"ask your teacher"*  I meant ***"ask your teacher"*** those specific questions, because then you might ask them *"OK .. if that's the case, can we do this using a desktop app (rather than an applet) using Swing (which offers Key Bindings)?"*. Key Bindings are easier to use and less prone to failing than **`KeyListener`** which is the only way to implement this in a pure AWT app (or applet).